# Issue with CTC Beam Search and Tensorflow C++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow, beam-search

I've frozen a tensorflow model that has as last node a ctc beam search. Using the pyhton API is possible to interpret the output tensor and convert to final sequence of labels. Since I want to use this frozen model in C++ I'm wondering how to use the C++ API in order to process this output tensor and get the final sequence of labels. Using the python API  I call this function "sparse_tensor_to_str" passing the tensor that i get after running the session. In my case the final sequence of labels is a string of characters.

```
    def sparse_tensor_to_str(self, spares_tensor: tf.SparseTensor):
    """
    :param spares_tensor:
    :return: a str
    """
    indices = spares_tensor.indices
    values = spares_tensor.values
    values = np.array([self.__ord_map[str(tmp)] for tmp in values])
    dense_shape = spares_tensor.dense_shape

    number_lists = np.ones(dense_shape, dtype=values.dtype)
    str_lists = []
    res = []
    for i, index in enumerate(indices):
        number_lists[index[0], index[1]] = values[i]
    for number_list in number_lists:
        str_lists.append([self.int_to_char(val) for val in number_list])
    for str_list in str_lists:
        res.append(''.join(c for c in str_list if c != '*'))
    return res
```

In C++ i do like the following:

```
string input_layer = "input:0";
string output_layer = "CTCBeamSearchDecoder:0";
std::vector<Tensor> inputs;

Status read_tensor_status = ReadTensorFromMat(candidate_plates_mat[i],input_height,input_width,input_mean,input_std, &inputs);
 if (!read_tensor_status.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << read_tensor_status;
    return;
 }

Tensor& resized_input_tensor = inputs[0];
std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
Status run_status = session->Run({{input_layer, resized_input_tensor}},{output_layer}, {}, &outputs);
if (!run_status.ok()) {
   LOG(ERROR) << "Running model failed: " << run_status;
   return;
}
std::cout<< outputs[0].tensor<tensorflow::int64, 2>() << std::endl
```

I get an output tensor that is a 9x2 tensor like this:

```
[[0, 0],
   [0, 1],
   [0, 2],
   [0, 3],
   [0, 4],
   [0, 5],
   [0, 6],
   [0, 7],
   [0, 8]]
```

where 9 is the actual length of the final string. Here i'm not capable of getting the right information, like in python, for estrapolating the final string.

Answer (score 0):

did you solve the problem?
i provide my solution for your reference

in python, your code should look like

```
# remember to set seq_len to fit for your case
decoded, log_prob = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(y, seq_len)
dense_decoded = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(decoded[0], default_value=-1)
```

in cpp, your code should look like

```
// you need to modify "outputName" if your model have prefix variable scope name
// SparseToDense is the name of tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense function
std::string outputName = "SparseToDense:0";
outputLayerNames_ = {outputName};


std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputDict_ = { std::make_pair(DefaultInputLayerName_, inputImageTensor_), 
                std::make_pair(DefaultTrainFlagName_, trainFlagTensor_),
                std::make_pair(DefaultSeqLenName_, inputSeqLenTensor_)};  
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs_;
sess_->Run(inputDict_, outputLayerNames_, {}, &outputs_);
std::cout<< outputs_[0].tensor<tensorflow::int64, 2>() << std::endl;
```

Remember you have to set **inputSeqLenTensor_** for sequence_length of tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder otherwise you will get nothing